# Switching multiple photodiode inputs to an op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches, photodiode

I am playing around with LEDs as (semi)wavelength selective photodetectors and have reproduced the circuit found in [Forest Mims' Make article](https://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/how-to-use-leds-to-detect-light/):

[image]

I have an operational circuit using an LM358 powered by an Arduino which is also reading the output.  I would like to expand this circuit to allow for multiple LEDs but would like to minimize the amount of components and analog read pins on the Arduino.  For my application, I do not need to measure the response from each LED simultaneously, so I would like to include some type of voltage controlled switch or similar device that would allow for this type of circuit:

[image]

(apologies for the image instead of schematic - for some reason circuit lab is hanging on the save and insert button for me)

I do not know if there is an IC that provides the functionality that I am looking for.  Essentially, I would like to use some type of communication protocol accessible from the Arduino that will allow me to digitally control which LED is connected to the op amp.

**Questions.**

1. What type of chip or circuitry would I need to cycle through the LEDs in this circuit and
2. given that this an educational rather than mission-critical project, are there any red flags that pop up with the proposed design?

Answer (score 7):

There's what's called "analog switches and multiplexers", which exactly fulfill the role of your pushbuttons here. Basically, all large silicon chip manufacturers have them (for example,  [Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/switches-multiplexers/analog/products.html#p3193max=0;0.045)).

However, the currents from photodiodes are *really* small and sensitive. You don't want to switch these, if it can be avoided. These switches can easily "leak" enough current into the current you want to measure (the photocurrent) to void the measurement.

Considering how cheap opamps are (a quad opamp costs insignificantly more than a single opamp in a package) and how little external components are needed (only R1, C1):

Build an amplifier for each of your diodes, and switch the *outputs* of these. That way, you'd be switching robust (as we call them, buffered) signals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of switching the outputs.  It is an obvious solution (after the fact).

Answer (score 1):

I think the component that you are looking for is an analog multiplexer such as this one: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a3357.pdf

But even thought the component has low ON resistance it will change the behaviour of your current design since it will add about 5 ohm in serie with the LED (from the datasheet).

Thus you circuit is not a "perfect" transcontuctance amplifier anymore, since the current out of the LED will induce a little voltage drop across the multiplexer which might prevent proper operation of your circuit (but I am not sure about that, but it seems that it would reduce the output current in some way, maybe someone knowlegable might be able to help more).

Comment: the resistance really isn't much of a problem – don't forget, it's 5Ω in series with 1MΩ – but the leakage current is.

Comment: Yes you are very right, my answer is not quite correct... thanks for the correction. Also I should have thought to propose a switching of multiple buffered signal I feel a bit stupid right now...